# Why is my while loop breaking under an if statement when the requirements are not met? (Text-Based Fighter Game)

Tags: python, function, class, while-loop

```
import random

class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, attack, dodge):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.attack = attack
        self.dodge = dodge
    
    def take_damage(self, damage):
        self.hp -= damage
    
    def hit(self, target):
        damage = self.attack
        miss = random.randint(1, 10 - self.dodge)
        if miss == random.randint(1, 10 - self.dodge):
          print(f"{target.name} dodged the attack!")
        else:
          target.take_damage(damage)
          print(f"{self.name} attacks {target.name} for {damage} damage!")

        
class Player(Character):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, attack, dodge):
        super().__init__(name, hp, attack, dodge)
        
class Enemy(Character):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, attack, dodge):
        super().__init__(name, hp, attack, dodge)

    fighter = Player("Fighter", 5, 3, 2)
    mage = Player("Mage" ,1, 5, 6)
    thief = Player("Thief" ,4, 3, 8)
    i = 1
    
    print("Welcome to Fighter Arena")
    x = input("Enter Your Name: ")
    print("Choose Your Character (fighter = 1 | mage = 2 | thief = 3)")
    choice = input()
    
    if choice == '1':
      user = fighter
    
    if choice == '2':
      user = mage
    
    if choice == '3':
      user = thief

    while True:
      ai = random.randint(1,3)
      if ai == 1:
        ai = fighter
        print("\nYou are fighting a fighter!")
        break
      if ai == 2:
        ai = mage
        print("\nYou are fighting a mage!")
        break
      if ai == 3:
        ai = thief
        print("\nYou are fighting a thief!")
        break
        
    player = user
    enemy = ai
    userCount = 0
    targetCount = 0

    for i in range(100):
      battles = True
      while battles is True:
          player = user
          enemy = ai
          print("\nRound", i)
          first = random.randint(1, 2)
          if first == 1:
            player.hit(enemy)
            if enemy.hp <= 0:
              print("You win!")
              userCount+=1
              break

              
            enemy.hit(player)
            if player.hp <= 0:
              print("You lose!")
              targetCount+=1
              break

              
          if first == 2:
            enemy.hit(player)
            if player.hp <= 0:
              print("You lose!")
              targetCount+=1
              break

              
            player.hit(enemy)
            if enemy.hp <= 0:
              print("You win!")
              userCount+=1
              break


    print(f"\nYou won", userCount, "times!")
    print(f"AI won", targetCount, "times!")
```

A problem that I am encountering is in the final game while loop. After an enemy or the player has dodged, it still ends the battle. The requirements for it to break is hp must be below or equal to zero and when they dodge they keep their health but it is still breaking. How do I fix it?

I attempted to rework the dodging within the attack function by changing the chance. At first I had target.take_damage(0) so I deleted that and left the if statement with just a print statement. This still did not work.

Comment: Does it print either "You win!" or "You lose!" before breaking?

Comment: If I dodge, I lose and if the enemy dodges, they lose. I believe it has something to do with redefining the stats of both enemy and player but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I'm no expert on Python so I'm not sure of this but: Could it be possible that even though you reassign ```player & enemy``` to ```user & ai``` the actual instances of the objects remain unchanged, and therefore the hitpoints remain below zero after round 1?

Comment: That's what I think it is but I do not know how to rearrange it. Once both of their health reaches 0, I think it is just a race to see who moves first.

Comment: What if you added another stat called ```maxHp``` and set the hp to that value. Then you can reset hp to maxHp at the start/end of the round.

Answer (score 0):

You had put `init()` instead of `__init__()`

**Here is the working code:**

```
import random
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, attack, dodge): 
        self.name = name 
        self.hp = hp 
        self.attack = attack 
        self.dodge = dodge

    def take_damage(self, damage):
        self.hp -= damage

    def hit(self, target):
        damage = self.attack
        miss = random.randint(1, 10 - self.dodge)
        if miss == random.randint(1, 10 - self.dodge):
            print(f"{target.name} dodged the attack!")
        else:
            target.take_damage(damage)
        print(f"{self.name} attacks {target.name} for {damage} damage!")

    
class Player(Character): 
    def __init__(self, name, hp, attack, dodge): 
        super().__init__(name, hp, attack, dodge)

class Enemy(Character): 
    def __init__(self, name, hp, attack, dodge): 
        super().__init__(name, hp, attack, dodge)

fighter = Player("Fighter", 5, 3, 2)
mage = Player("Mage" ,1, 5, 6)
thief = Player("Thief" ,4, 3, 8)
i = 1

print("Welcome to Fighter Arena")
x = input("Enter Your Name: ")
print("Choose Your Character (fighter = 1 | mage = 2 | thief = 3)")
choice = input()

if choice == '1':
  user = fighter

if choice == '2':
  user = mage

if choice == '3':
  user = thief

while True:
  ai = random.randint(1,3)
  if ai == 1:
    ai = fighter
    print("\nYou are fighting a fighter!")
    break
  if ai == 2:
    ai = mage
    print("\nYou are fighting a mage!")
    break
  if ai == 3:
    ai = thief
    print("\nYou are fighting a thief!")
    break
    
player = user
enemy = ai
userCount = 0
targetCount = 0

for i in range(100):
  battles = True
  while battles is True:
      player = user
      enemy = ai
      print("\nRound", i)
      first = random.randint(1, 2)
      if first == 1:
        player.hit(enemy)
        if enemy.hp <= 0:
          print("You win!")
          userCount+=1
          break

          
        enemy.hit(player)
        if player.hp <= 0:
          print("You lose!")
          targetCount+=1
          break

          
      if first == 2:
        enemy.hit(player)
        if player.hp <= 0:
          print("You lose!")
          targetCount+=1
          break

          
        player.hit(enemy)
        if enemy.hp <= 0:
          print("You win!")
          userCount+=1
          break


print(f"\nYou won", userCount, "times!")
print(f"AI won", targetCount, "times!")
```